# Delay audio before playing

Tags: c#

I was having an issue where received audio data would play stuttered so I came up with the idea to put a slight delay before it started playing so the application would have more time to collect audio sections before it started playing. The idea being that it'll be playing through the collected audio as the rest comes in to the application before it's needed.

```
//A raised event from a udp class when data is received (from it's own thread)
void udpClient_DataReceived(byte[] bytes) 
{
    audioQueue.Enqueue (bytes); //ConcurrentQueue

    if (audioQueue.Count > 10 && !playing) { //count > 10 is about a one second delay
        playing = true;
        PlayQueue ();
    }
}

private void PlayQueue()
{
    byte[] a;
    while (audioQueue.Count > 0) {
        audioQueue.TryDequeue (out a);
        audIn.PlayAudio (a);
    }
    playing = false;
}
```

However the code has 2 issues:

1) If the audio length is shorter than the set limit, it wont play until more audio is collected. So I need some kind of delay that doesn't require a minimum amount of data to trigger it.

2) Sometimes the last few sections get missed and remain in the queue for the next play. There is a race between the data coming in and the while loop of the PlayQueue function finishing. Sometimes it finishes before all data is received.

I'm not quite sure how to solve these two issues in my code and would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know how to work properly with events such as ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent, you can find yourself drowning with excess code only to try and synchronize the Set & Wait on them, sometime even adding additional events just to do so.

Usually in cases of Consumer / Producer problems, I tend to use the Interlocked class and it's amazing atomic functions.
It's much more clean and there is no risk of Deadlocks.

This solution will buffer 1 sec every time the queue is empty.

```
    bool play = true; // global keep running flag.
    int m_numberOfSamples = 0;

    // Call this ONCE, at the start of your app.
    void Init()
    {
        // perform any initialization here... maybe allocate queue..
    }

    void EnqueueSample(byte[] bytes)
    {
        audioQueue.Enqueue(bytes); //ConcurrentQueue

        int numberOfSamples = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numberOfSamples);
        if(numberOfSamples == 1)
        {
            // this is a case of first sample
            // Start a Task with a 1 sec delay
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Buffering...
                    // if you want to buffer x samples, use 1000*x/SampleRate instead of 1000 for 1 sec.
                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                    PlayQueue();
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

    private void PlayQueue()
    {
        // if we are here, there is at least 1 sample already.
        byte[] a;
        int remainingSamples = 0;
        do
        {
            if (audioQueue.TryDequeue(out a))  // check if we succesfull got an array
            {
                audIn.PlayAudio(a);
                remainingSamples = Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numberOfSamples);
            }
        }
        while (play && remainingSamples > 0);
        // we got out either by play = false or remainingSamples == 0
        // if remainingSamples == 0, we will get back here with a different **Task**
        // after a new sample has entered into the queue and again we buffer 1 sec using the Task.Delay
    }
```

Comment: But is the numberofSamples in this code not the same as TryDequeue returning false? This code might also spin a second Thread (but the first thread will almost end therafter). Your suggestion about samplerate is key.

Comment: @rene Working with an external int **m_numberOfSamples** with Interlocked gives you additional benefits that you can't achieve with just a ConcurrentQueue without locking the queue and query the Count of the queue.
With the way I implemented it, you could even have multiple producers and 1 consumer, only the 1st producer which have increased the number of samples in the queue from 0 to 1 will spin up the thread.

I agree, this code could spin another Thread, but only when the current thread has already finished it's job and is about to leave the method.

Comment: Actually I think I spoke too soon. It doesn't seem like the Task.Delay is doing anything and I'm ending up with a lot of threads being created. Is `Thread.Sleep(1000);` in the if statement before you create the task acceptable? I've heard different opinions on if you should use `Thread.Sleep()` or not;

Comment: Right, sorry about that, forgot the Wait() on the Task.Delay

Comment: Ok thanks, that seems to have it all working correctly again. I'm going to do a bit more testing before I accept the answer again just to be sure.

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000); in the if statement before I create the Task, will only block your producer for 1 sec, it will not block the consumer for 1 sec.
We still want the producer to feed the queue with more samples while the consumer waits.

Answer (score 2):

The udpclient will raise the datareceived event everytime a new packet arrives. As the access to the shared state (ConcurrentQueue and playing) is not serialized you can end up with two or more threads running the code in PlayQueue or when the queue gets empty your play thread stops while still data may arrive from the udpclient. Another issue is tat you don't check for the result TryDequeue.

I would start by having ONE and only one thread that reads your ConcurrentQueue and use an [EventwaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  derived type to do cross thread signaling.

Your code goes in that case like this:

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Thread audio;
bool play = true; // global keep running flag.

// Call this ONCE, at the start of your app.
void Init()
{
    audio  = new Thread(PlayQueue);
    audio.Start();
}

void udpClient_DataReceived(byte[] bytes) 
{
    audioQueue.Enqueue (bytes); //ConcurrentQueue

    mre.Set(); // this signals that we have data

    // disbale the timer if the stream is done
    // and/or set play to false
    // based on bytes received in your byte array
}

private void PlayQueue()
{
    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); // play after 1 second
    var timeEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    aTimer.Elapsed += (s,e) => { timeEvent.Set(); };  // the time will start the play
    byte[] a;
    mre.WaitOne();  // wait until there is data
    atimer.Enabled = true; // it will start playimg after 1000 miliseconds
    timeEvent.WaitOne(); // wait for the timer

    while (play) {
        if (audioQueue.TryDequeue (out a))  // check if we succesfull got an array
        {
           audIn.PlayAudio (a);
        }
    }
}
```

Consider this as the simplest solution that could work. I'm not claiming this is all the nuts and bolts needed to have production grade multi-threading code...

Comment: Thanks for the threading tips but this doesn't solve the first issue because you could have an audio sample shorter than the compared value. Lowering the value could bring back the stuttering. I think there needs to be another way to do the delay (perhaps triggering a timer or something). It also doesnt reset the delay once playing has ended.

Comment: How much bytes do you need for 1 second? That it doesn't reset is correct but there is also no info in your question how you can detect that, in other words, how you know the stream has ended. It can easily be added by bringing the mre.WaitOne() in the loop. If you know when a stream ends you can call mre.Reset. That will block the PlayQueue method again.

Comment: Added a timer and moved it in PlayQueue

Comment: That is true. Currently there is nothing about the bytes that would dictate the end so once I do that (which in itself could be it's own provlen) then it won't be hard to finish. Thanks. Once this gets coded up and tested, if this works I'll accept your answer.